# Android RelativeLayout header issue

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a very simple problem, but I am clearly doing something wrong. I've tried many ways to do this, but there's always something screwing up.

I have a ListView with a horizontal LinearLayout serving as a header. I want to have < and > serving as "back and next" widgets, on the very left and very right portions of the LinearLayout. The `LIST HEADER` portion should be centered between them.

Making `LIST HEADER` have the attribute `android:layout_width="match_parent"` cuts off the right hand arrow. Otherwise it lays on top of the left arrow, even though it appears after the `LIST HEADER` `TextView` in the XML file.

```
<     LIST HEADER     >
List item number 1
List item number 2
List item number 3
```

I'm not new to Android at this stage but this seems basic. Any help would be appreciated.
I should add that I'm not using eclipse.

CURRENT XML (sort of messy after trying so many things, apologies):

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/LeftFormulaHeaderLayout"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:textSize="@dimen/text_huge"
      android:id="@+id/LeftFormulaHeader"
      android:text="&lt;"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="200dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="@dimen/text_huge"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:scrollHorizontally="false"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:id="@+id/FormulaHeader"/>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/RightFormulaHeaderLayout"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/RightFormulaHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_huge"
    android:text="&gt;"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>


  <ListView
  android:id="@+id/TheList"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#000033"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/empty_list_item"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:text="@string/empty_list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue: `gravity` affects positioning of the text within the `TextView`. You want `alignParentLeft`/-`Right` and `centerHorizontal` for what you are doing (although `gravity="center"` remains to keep the header centered in its view).

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:textSize="@dimen/text_huge"
  android:id="@+id/LeftFormulaHeader"
  android:text="&lt;"/>
<TextView
  android:layout_width="200dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="@dimen/text_huge"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:scrollHorizontally="false"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:id="@+id/FormulaHeader"
  android:text="HEADER"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/RightFormulaHeader"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:textSize="@dimen/text_huge"
android:text="&gt;"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Other than modifying the `RelativeLayout`'s `layout_height` to be `wrap_content`, this solution works just fine. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below code with the help of `RelativeLayout` instead of messing up with `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
   >

         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />

               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OutputScreenShot:**

[image]

Even this code helps center your views in layout vertically. You can Change the 2nd `ImageView` to `TextView` to have a text to be displayed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to work with the weight attribute here:

```
<!-- Your header layout. -->

<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal" weight_sum="1">

    <!-- Button left. -->

    <TextView layout_width="30dp" layout_height="30dp" />

    <!-- Headline. -->

    <TextView layout_width="0dp" layout_height="30dp" layout_weight="1" gravity="center" />

    <!-- Button right. -->

    <TextView layout_width="30dp" layout_height="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The above code is not working for copy/paste. You need to add your details. I just wanted to point out the most important things:

- For this solution it's important to have a fixed width for the left/right widgets
- Note that the headline has a width of 0dp ...
- ... and a weight of 1!

So the headline will end up taking all the wrapper's available space except the 2*30dp of the left/right widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Try out with my below code i have done some relevant changes.

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:orientation="vertical" >
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" >
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>         <RelativeLayout
>             android:id="@+id/LeftFormulaHeaderLayout"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/LeftFormulaHeader"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="left"
>                 android:text="&lt;"
>                 android:textSize="20sp" />
>         </RelativeLayout>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/FormulaHeader"
>             android:layout_width="200dip"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:ellipsize="end"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>             android:scrollHorizontally="false"
>             android:singleLine="true"
>             android:text="kajsgfuisagf"
>             android:textSize="20sp" />
>         <RelativeLayout
>             android:id="@+id/RightFormulaHeaderLayout"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/RightFormulaHeader"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="center"
>                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                 android:text=">"
>                 android:textSize="20sp" />
>         </RelativeLayout>
>     </RelativeLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
>  <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/TheList"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_weight="1"
>     android:background="#000033"
>     android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/empty_list_item"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:text="empty_list"
>     android:visibility="gone" />
> ```

[image]